# OpenGL Drawing with VBO

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, 3d, vbo

Iam trying to write a small Opengl program to draw a single triangle using only Vertex Buffer Objects (without using VAO)s but whenever i want to compile it, it only shows a blue screen

Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <GLUT/glut.h>
#include <OpenGL/gl3.h>

GLuint VBO;
GLuint VAO;

void display();

float vertex[] = {-1.0, 0.0 , 0.0,
                   0.0 , 1.0 , 0.0 ,
                   1.0 , 0.0 , 0.0 };

int main (int argc, char *argv[])

{
glutInit(&argc, argv);
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE);
glutInitWindowSize(1000, 400);
glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
glutCreateWindow("My First GLUT/OpenGL Window");
glutDisplayFunc(display);
glutMainLoop();
return 0;
}

 void display()

{
glClearColor(0, 0, 1,1);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

glGenBuffers(1,&VBO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,9 *sizeof(vertex),vertex, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3,GL_FLOAT, GL_TRUE, 0, 0);


glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

glutSwapBuffers();
};
```

Comment: Where are your shader(s)?  Alternatively, why aren't you using `glVertexPointer()`?

Comment: Iam new to Opengl programming & i  wanted to explore the different ways of drawing with opengl so following some online tutorials (that didn't cover every bit of the program)i came up with this code, though i know that we should provide our shader programs ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three problems:

- Your code misses setting the viewport (if the window happens to be created with a size of 0×0 and gets resized only later the initial viewport size will be 0×0).
- Your use of the `sizeof` operator is wrong. `vertex` is a statically allocated array, and so the `sizeof` operator will return the total size of the vertex array, nout just the size of a single element. So in that particular case just `sizeof(vertex)` without multiplying it with 9 would suffice.

And last but not least, and the true cause of your problem:

- Where are your shaders? Using generic vertex attributes, and of course mandatory by OpenGL-3 you must supply a valid combination of a vertex and fragment shader. Without those, nothing will render.

Comment: actually i came up to all these problems from internet tutorials there are some tutorials that multiplies the sizeof operator by a constant, and regarding the shaders i already know that vertex and fragment shaders are mandatory but as i mentioned it before there are some online tutorials that doesn't mention all of the aspects of  the program, i thought that by not specifying a shader We let OpenGl to use some sort of default shader programs maybe like a simple pass-through shader :P ,anyway  thank you for your answer..

Comment: @BulBul: There's no default shader in OpenGL. Using OpenGL-2 and using non generic vertex attributes (glVertexPointer, glNormalPointer, glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY) and such) you can default to the fixed function pipeline. Regarding the sizeof operator, I presume that tutorial you mention either wrote something like `sizeof(v[0])` or `sizeof(*v)` and did work on a pointer not a statically allocated array. Since you didn't knew about this subtlety I strongly suggest you polish up your C/C++ knowledge.

Comment: from the definition of one of the C programming books that i've read states that >>> the name of an array (without specifying the index) is a pointer to the first element in that array for example: "vertex" equivalent to "vertex[0]", but it seems like sizeof() operator works in a whole different way than i've expected.

Comment: @BulBul: Yes, in principle a symbol that created through an array definition can be used just like a pointer. However the symbol of a statically allocated array behaves differently as the symbol of a pointer, to which an array symbol trivially casts.